# user.setPassword is not a function - passport local mongoose

Tags: express, mongoose, passport.js

I am implementing a reset password feature on for the users of my website. However, it seems to throw this error when the user confirms new password at the reset.ejs page.

The following steps are being performed correctly:

- Token sent on mail
- When clicked on token, new password page opens

When user enters new password and confirm new password and hits the button to save the new password, the function in users.js `user.setPassword` does not work as the error is mentioned below. It is a built in function of passport-local-mongoose.

> ERROR: user.savePassword is not a function

Including all the code files below:

> users.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer({dest: './uploads'});
var passport = require('passport');
var mongoose  = require('mongoose');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var randomstring = require("randomstring");
var User = require('../models/user');
var data=require('../models/data');
var checklist=require("../models/checklist");
var async = require("async");
var crypto = require("crypto");
var passportLocalMongoose=require("passport-local-mongoose");

// "use strict";
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
      user: 'dataseedltd@gmail.com',
      pass: 'mypassword'
    }
  });  


/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});


router.get('/register/:type', function(req, res, next) {

  res.render('user/register.ejs',{title:'Register',type:req.params.type});
});

router.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('user/login.ejs', {title:'Login'});
});

router.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local',{failureRedirect:'/users/login', failureFlash: 'Invalid username or password'}),
  function(req, res) {
        var previouspath=req.cookies.previouspath;    

        if(req.cookies.checklist==undefined){
           req.flash('success', 'You are now logged in');
             if(req.user.as=='seller'){
                if(previouspath!=undefined){
                if(previouspath.length!=0)
                res.redirect(previouspath);
                else
                res.redirect('/buyer');
                }
                else
                res.redirect('/buyer');            
                }
             else {
                if(previouspath!=undefined){
                      if(previouspath.length!=0)
                      res.redirect(previouspath);
                      else
                      res.redirect('/buyer');
                }
                else
                res.redirect('/buyer');
             }
          }
        else{
         var ids=req.cookies.checklist['data']

                            var checks=[];
                        for(var i=0;i<ids.length;i++){
                            checks.push({user:req.user,data:ids[i]});
                        }
                  checklist.insertMany(checks,function(err, d) {
                     if(err)console.log(err); 

                     res.clearCookie('checklist'); 
               req.flash('success', 'You are now logged in');
             if(req.user.as=='seller'){
                 if(previouspath.length!=0)
                res.redirect(previouspath);
                else
                res.redirect('/seller')

             }
             else {
                if(previouspath.length!=0)
                res.redirect(previouspath);
                else
                res.redirect('/buyer')
             }
         }); 
        } 
});

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.getUserById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done){
  User.getUserByUsername(username, function(err, user){
    if(err) throw err;
    if(!user){
      return done(null, false, {message: 'Unknown User'});
    }

    User.comparePassword(password, user.password, function(err, isMatch){
      if(err) return done(err);
      if(isMatch){
        return done(null, user);
      } else {
        return done(null, false, {message:'Invalid Password'});
      }
    });
  });
}));

router.post('/register/:type',function(req, res, next) {
  var name = req.body.name;
  var email = req.body.email;
  var username = req.body.username;
  var institution=req.body.institution;
    var education=req.body.education;
    var proffession=req.body.proffession;
  var   country=req.body.country;
  //check if email does not already exists
  //check if username does not already exists

  User.find({ $or: [ { email: { $eq: req.body.email } }, { username: { $eq: req.body.username } } ] },function(err,data){
    if(err)console.log(err);
    if(data.length!=0){

    console.log(data.length);
     req.flash('success','email or username is repeated.');
     res.redirect('/users/register/'+req.params.type);

    }
    else
    {

        var password = req.body.password;
        var password2 = req.body.password2;
        var as      =req.params.type;

        // Form Validator
        req.checkBody('name','Name field is required').notEmpty();
        req.checkBody('email','Email field is required').notEmpty();
        req.checkBody('email','Email is not valid').isEmail();
        req.checkBody('username','Username field is required').notEmpty();
        req.checkBody('password','Password field is required').notEmpty();

        // Check Errors
        var errors = req.validationErrors();

        if(errors){
            res.render('user/register.ejs', {
                errors: errors
            });
        } else{
            var newUser = new User({
            name: name,
            email: email,
            username: username,
            password: password,
            as          :as,
            institution:institution,
             education:education,
             proffession:proffession,
            country:country
          });

          User.createUser(newUser, function(err, user){
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log(user);
          });

          // res.location('/');
      var token=randomstring.generate(7);
      var to=req.body.email;
      var subject='Email Confirmation from dataSeed ';
      var message='<h1>Use this code to register </h1><p>Your verification Code is: <h2>'+token+'</h2></p>';
        var mailOptions=sendmail(to,subject,message);
        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
                          if (error) {
                              console.log(error);
                          }
                          else
                          {
                                res.render('user/emailconfirmation.ejs',{username:req.body.username,token:token});

                          }
        });



        }



      }


  });  

  function sendmail(to,subject,message){

    var mailOptions = {
    from: 'dataseedltd@gmail.com',
    to: to,
    subject: subject,
    html: message 

    };
    return mailOptions;

}

  router.post('/emailconfirmation/:token',function(req, res) {
      if(req.params.token==req.body.token){
              req.flash('success', 'You are now registered and can login');
                res.redirect('/');        
        }
        else{
            User.remove({username:req.body.username},function(err,data){
              if(err)console.log(err);
              res.redirect('/');

              });  
        }
  });
});

router.get('/logout', function(req, res){
  req.logout();
  req.flash('success', 'You are now logged out');
  res.redirect('/users/login');
});


//Forgot Password
router.get('/forgot',function(req,res){
  res.render("forgotpassword.ejs");
  });


  router.post('/forgot', function(req, res, next) {
  async.waterfall([
    function(done) {
      crypto.randomBytes(20, function(err, buf) {
        var token = buf.toString('hex');
        done(err, token);
      });
    },
    function(token, done) {
      User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, function(err, user) {
        if (!user) {
          req.flash('success', 'No account with that email address exists.');
          return res.redirect('/users/forgot');
        }

        user.resetPasswordToken = token;
        user.resetPasswordExpires = Date.now() + 3600000; // 1 hour

        user.save(function(err) {
          done(err, token, user);
        });
      });
    },
    function(token, user, done) {
      var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'Gmail', 
        auth: {
          user: 'dataseedltd@gmail.com',
          pass: 'mypassword'
        }
      });
      var mailOptions = {
        to: user.email,
        from: 'dataseedltd@gmail.com',
        subject: 'Node.js Password Reset',
        text: 'You are receiving this because you (or someone else) have requested the reset of the password for your account.\n\n' +
          'Please click on the following link, or paste this into your browser to complete the process:\n\n' +
          'http://' + req.headers.host + '/users/reset/' + token + '\n\n' +
          'If you did not request this, please ignore this email and your password will remain unchanged.\n'
      };
      smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err) {
        console.log('mail sent');
        req.flash('success', 'An e-mail has been sent to ' + user.email + ' with further instructions.');
        done(err, 'done');
      });
    }
  ], function(err) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.redirect('/users/forgot');
  });
});

router.get('/reset/:token', function(req, res) {
  User.findOne({ resetPasswordToken: req.params.token, resetPasswordExpires: { $gt: Date.now() } }, function(err, user) {
    if (!user) {
      req.flash('success', 'Password reset token is invalid or has expired.');
      return res.redirect('/users/forgot');
    }
    res.render('reset', {token: req.params.token});
  });
});

router.post('/reset/:token', function(req, res) {
  async.waterfall([
    function(done) {
      User.findOne({ resetPasswordToken: req.params.token, resetPasswordExpires: { $gt: Date.now() } }, function(err, user) {
        if (!user) {
          req.flash('error', 'Password reset token is invalid or has expired.');
          return res.redirect('back');
        }
        if(req.body.password === req.body.confirm) {
          user.setPassword(req.body.password, function(err) {
            user.resetPasswordToken = undefined;
            user.resetPasswordExpires = undefined;

            user.save(function(err) {
              req.logIn(user, function(err) {
                done(err, user);
              });
            });
          })
        } else {
            req.flash("error", "Passwords do not match.");
            return res.redirect('back');
        }
      });
    },
    function(user, done) {
      var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'Gmail', 
        auth: {
          user: 'dataseedltd@gmail.com',
          pass: 'mypassword'
        }
      });
      var mailOptions = {
        to: user.email,
        from: 'dataseedltd@gmail.com',
        subject: 'Your password has been changed',
        text: 'Hello,\n\n' +
          'This is a confirmation that the password for your account ' + user.email + ' has just been changed.\n'
      };
      smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err) {
        req.flash('success', 'Success! Your password has been changed.');
        done(err);
      });
    }
  ], function(err) {
    res.redirect('/login');
  });
});
module.exports = router;
```

users.js (model):

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
var passportLocalMongoose=require("passport-local-mongoose");
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/dataseed');

var db = mongoose.connection;

// User Schema
var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        index: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String
    },
    email: {
        type: String
    },
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    profileimage:{
        type: String
    },
    as:{
        type:String
    },
    institution:{
        type:String
    },
    education:{
        type:String

    },
    proffession:{
        type:String
    },
    country:{
        type:String
    },
    resetPasswordToken: String,
    resetPasswordExpires: Date

});

var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports.getUserById = function(id, callback){
    User.findById(id, callback);
}

module.exports.getUserByUsername = function(username, callback){
    var query = {username: username};
    User.findOne(query, callback);
}

module.exports.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, hash, callback){
    bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, hash, function(err, isMatch) {
        callback(null, isMatch);
    });
}

module.exports.createUser = function(newUser, callback){
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
        bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
            newUser.password = hash;
            newUser.save(callback);
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you don't have a method called `setPassword` defined under user model. This is mainly because you haven't plugin the `passport-local-mongoose` to `UserSchema`. Add `UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);` before creating the model from `UserSchema`. like this

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
    var passportLocalMongoose=require("passport-local-mongoose");
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/dataseed');

    var db = mongoose.connection;

    // User Schema
    var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        username: {
            type: String,
            index: true
        },
        password: {
            type: String
        },
        email: {
            type: String
        },
        name: {
            type: String
        },
        profileimage:{
            type: String
        },
        as:{
            type:String
        },
        institution:{
            type:String
        },
        education:{
            type:String

        },
        proffession:{
            type:String
        },
        country:{
            type:String
        },
        resetPasswordToken: String,
        resetPasswordExpires: Date

    });

    UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

    var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Comment: https://github.com/nax3t/yelp-camp-refactored/blob/password-reset/views/forgot.ejs

Im following the above mentioned tutorial, couldnt find that function anywhere

Comment: I am getting the same error I have plugin the passportLocalMongoose as shown above.

Comment: hi @TRomesh, Should I use scryto instead of passport-local-mongoose ?